# How to properly combine two txt files into 1 list

Tags: python-3.x

The goal of this is take two text inputs from the user combine them and then print the elements. I think I'm along the right path but when i run this code I get a huge table with elements that make absolutely no sense. 
Here is the code that I have currently:

```
      defining the read function
def read(pulsar_name,signal_strength):
    #opening and reading data from first line
    pulsars = open(pulsar_name,"r").read()
    #opening and reading data from second line
    signals = open(signal_strength,"r").read()
    #creating a new empty list
    astro_list = []
    #appending pulsar values to list
    for all_pulsar_name in range(0,len(pulsars)):
        astro_list.append(pulsar_name)
    #appending signal data to list
    for all_signal_strength in range(0,len(signals)):
        astro_list.append(signal_strength)
    with open("z.txt", "w") as out:
        for i in range(0,len(astro_list)):
            return(pulsar_name[i].rstrip(),signal_strength[i])

#defining the main function
def main():

    #displaying a description of what the program does
    purpose = "This program proccess data from the Purdue Pulsar Laboratory"
    underheading = "=" * len(purpose)
    print(purpose)
    print(underheading)
    print("It reads the data from 2 files containing the pulsar name and signal strength, \nthen combines them and displays the results.")
    #accepting inputs from the user about file names
    pulsar_name = input("\nPulsar name file: ")
    signal_strength = input("Signal strength: ")
    #calling
    astro_list = read(pulsar_name,signal_strength)
    read(pulsar_name,signal_strength)
    #reading values
    print("\nAnalyzing data from" , pulsar_name, "and", signal_strength, "files...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,pulsar_name,"...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,signal_strength,"...")
    print("     ","Combining values...")
    #displaying the top part of the table/ counting the number of elements that are in the list
    print("\nThe combined BOOYA data includes" ,len(astro_list), "values.")
    print(astro_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know you all don't have access to the files, and it would be a pain to probably give them to you but I just need to know how to basically combine the lists that I have already. The read function is supposed to take two arguments which I have identified. I'm not exactly getting an error code it's just that I know I am not properly combining the lists. An example of the output is so one text file would have the ALPHABET and one would have the NUMBERS for example:

[image]

this is what the output of my code looks like now. 
[image]

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.  It will be hard to propose how to combine the data without seeing it.

Comment: please provide a sample input and sample output. It’d be easier to debug

Comment: @yash I've updated the question with a sample

Comment: You have to provide us with some idea of what the data in the files looks like. It would also be helpful if you copy and paste the output of this program.

Comment: I explained the one text file would be the LETTERS, and the next would be the NUMBERS . So like in the OUTPUT example you have one letter and one number as in M3, M4 etc etc. The output of this program literally never ends it just keeps outputting random combinations of n and numbers.

Comment: @yash  I've updated the question again

Comment: @francium i've updated the question again

Comment: You should first read the very first comment by Stephen Rauch carefully, especially the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable part.

Comment: The process for doing something like this is something along the lines of (assuming the signals and pulsars data is of equal length): read from a file and store in a variable. Use the string `.split()` and `.strip()` methods to split up the lines and remove whitespaces. The iterate over the data using `for i in range(len(signals))` and in that for loop do something like `astro_list.append(pulsars[i].capitalize() + signals[i])`. Finally return astro_list (after the for loop, not inside it)

Comment: @MinnaAdelRubio posted an answer, with certain assumptions of course

Comment: @MinnaAdelRubio Does the answer I posted looks correct?

Answer (score 0):

As @francium mentioned in the comments, I assumed pulsars data and signal data are of same length and modified the read function.

```
def read(pulsar_name,signal_strength):
    astro_list = []
    #open the files
    with open(pulsar_name, 'r') as p, open(signal_strength, 'r') as s:
        #read both of the files
        pulsar_lines = p.readlines()
        signal_lines = s.readlines()

        for i in range(len(pulsar_lines)):
            #strip each line and split it on spaces on both files
            pline = pulsar_lines[i].strip().split()
            sline = signal_lines[i].strip().split()
            astro_list.append([])

            #take element from pline and sline and combine them
            for j in range(len(pline)):
                astro_list[-1].append(pline[j].capitalize() + sline[j])

    #write the astro_list to file named z.txt
    with open('z.txt', 'w') as out:
        for i in range(len(astro_list)):
            out.write(' '.join(astro_list[i]))
            out.write('\n')

    return astro_list

#defining the main function
def main():

    #displaying a description of what the program does
    purpose = "This program proccess data from the Purdue Pulsar Laboratory"
    underheading = "=" * len(purpose)
    print(purpose)
    print(underheading)
    print("It reads the data from 2 files containing the pulsar name and signal strength, \nthen combines them and displays the results.")
    #accepting inputs from the user about file names
    pulsar_name = input("\nPulsar name file: ")
    signal_strength = input("Signal strength: ")
    #calling
    astro_list = read(pulsar_name,signal_strength)
    #reading values
    print("\nAnalyzing data from" , pulsar_name, "and", signal_strength, "files...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,pulsar_name,"...")
    print("     ","Reading from" ,signal_strength,"...")
    print("     ","Combining values...")
    #displaying the top part of the table/ counting the number of elements that are in the list
    print("\nThe combined BOOYA data includes" ,len(sum(astro_list, [])), "values.")
    print(underheading)
    for l in astro_list:
        print(*l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Following is my **signal.txt**

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

and **pulsar.txt**

```
A B C D E F G H
I J K L M N O P
```

Output when i run the above program:

```
This program proccess data from the Purdue Pulsar Laboratory
============================================================
It reads the data from 2 files containing the pulsar name and signal strength,
then combines them and displays the results.

Pulsar name file: pulsar.txt
Signal strength: signal.txt

Analyzing data from pulsar.txt and signal.txt files...
      Reading from pulsar.txt ...
      Reading from signal.txt ...
      Combining values...

The combined BOOYA data includes 16 values.
============================================================
1A 2B 3C 4D 5E 6F 7G 8H
8I 7J 6K 5L 4M 3N 2O 1P
```